# What's the life span of a variable in a program (in Java)?

Tags: variables, oop, static-variables

Can you tell me how long a variable lives in a program (in Java). i.e. variables declared inside methods, variables used in parameters, STATIC variables, variables used to return from a method, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. References declared inside methods go out of scope when the method exits.
2. Parameters passed to methods won't be eligible for GC until there are no more references to them or they go out of scope.
3. Static references are associated with a class and live as long as the class is loaded.
4. Returned  references won't be eligible for GC until there are no more references to them or they go out of scope.

Comment: You are confusing variables (1 and 3) with objects (2 and 4).

Comment: What if those variables are objects?  You sound like you're confusing primitives and objects.

Comment: Variables can't *be* objects, these are two completely different concepts. At most a variable can contain a reference to an object.

Comment: Depends on what you call a variable - they can't refer to objects?  Why the "at most" qualifier.  I call bullsh!t on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Java are guaranteed to live as long as they are referenceable through a [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the [root set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_set#Tracing_garbage_collectors). This is a conservative approximation of the application's live objects¹.

**Edit:** Is this question concerning *object lifetime*, or *variable scope*? We have some mixed terminology going on.

¹ A live object is an object that will be referenced again before the application terminates.

Comment: re: mixed terminology. No kidding. I like the way duffymo's answer toggles back and forth between the two. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Life Spam hierarchy

Class Variable > Instance Variable > Method variable > Local Variable

Class variable has the longest life spam and local variable has least, in-fact the local variable are only accessible within the block we define them in.